# preg_match_all - No matches for non-unix file formats

Tags: php, encoding, preg-match-all

I used the following code to get the file contents:

```php
$file_contents = file_get_contents('note.txt');
```

Then i used preg_match_all to get some matches.

---

**What is the problem then ?**

The problem is if the file format of `note.txt` is not set to `UNIX`, preg_match_all will not match anything whatever is the file encoding is!

Comment: What is your regular expression?

Comment: The regular expression just works fine on the same file when i change its format to `UNIX` from `Windows` or `Mac` ..

Comment: show your regular expression

Comment: Ok - so just set the file type to `UNIX`. What's the problem?

Comment: @DevZer0 The Regex works fine, It gets the result i want when the file format set to `UNIX` , So there is no any problem with the regex, and im pretty sure it doesnt contain any problem.

Comment: @MikeW The problem is the note.txt file will be uploaded by the users, so i cant guarantee for myself that they will convert it to `UNIX`

Comment: Line endings are different. Your regex will need to know that. If you don't want to post it here that's fine, but don't expect to get much help.

Comment: @MikeW Sure i can post it .. this is the regex, `\A\n*\/\*\n*(([^:\n]*:[^\n;]*\n)+)`

Comment: there u go. your not using `[\r\n]+` for line ends

Comment: I think the problem is the line endings in Windows & Mac files, which are `\r\n`. Unix files use just a `\n`. Your regex is matching on newlines in several places, but you probably need to match on `\r?\n` in those places (i.e. 0 or 1 `\r` followed by `\n`). I don't have time to code it, and without a sample of your data I probably wouldn't get it right anyway. Try it.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much guys. Didnt expect that the problem from the regex, that was the last thing i will think about. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't account for windows EOL, or OSX EOL. Below is a fix for it.

```
\A[\r\n]+\/\*[\r\n]+(([^:\r\n]*:[^\r\n;]*[\r\n]+)+)
```